# Intellij IDEA cannot resolve dependencies in multimodule project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I decide to try Intellij Idea, and I imported existing Maven multi-module project from Eclipse into Idea. But Idea can't resolve dependencies related with GWT classes and some dependencies between maven modules. I tried to re-import maven projects - it don't help.

How I can solve this problem?

Additional info: 
Project was imported from Eclipse's workspace (with eclipse specific files, such as `.project` etc. But I don't think it can be problem). GWT dependencies are exist in `pom.xml`, but all classes from GWT highlighted with red color. In eclipse this project work fine.

Comment: You need to give some more information. Right now there is not sufficient information for anyone to give you any help.

Comment: @maba I improved my question with additional info. Please review it. Thanks

Comment: IntelliJ has the ability to open eclise workspaces/projects but in this case you should point IntelliJ to the `pom.xml`, nothing else. Try again.

Comment: @maba yes, I pointed IntelliJ to `pom.xml`, not to project directory

Comment: I work with Maven multi-module projects in IntelliJ on a daily basis and have never had any problems. Please show us some part of your `pom.xml` as I guess that you have made some changes in ecplise to make it work and those changes has not been reflected in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: I'd like to help you with this but you really have to give some more information. IntelliJ is an excellent IDE so don't give up yet.

Comment: @maba thanks for help. I solved this problem. The problem was related with invalid maven's `settings.xml`.

Comment: What was the "fix"? Thanks. Also, is this related to intellij 12?

Comment: @Alex here's no fix, simply my `setting.xml` was not correct.

Comment: @MyTitle can you show us an example of your settings.xml ? I am facing the same problem. I do not have a settings.xml. If I right click > maven > create settings.xml. I do not have it by default and multi module projects are not importing dependencies.